# Is there anyway I can limit my forecast to a upper limit using bsts package?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, forecasting, bsts

I am using bsts package for forecasting. I need my forecast to be less than the upper limit. Like shown in the below figure.

[image: si]

FaceBook Prophet allows this by an option. I would like to do the similar stuff using bsts package. Is there anyway I can limit my forecast to a upper limit using bsts package?

Answer (score 0):

As with any other time series method you can forecast a transformation of $z = g(y)$ instead of $y$ directly. Such that the inverse of the transformation is bounded.

If your example has upper $b$ and lower $a$ limits you can use the following transformation:
$$
z =  g(y) = \log\left(\frac{y-a}{b-y}\right)
$$
with
$$
y = g^{-1}(z) = (b-a)\cdot \frac{e^z}{1+e^z} + a
$$
as discussed here https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-within-limits/

If it only has a lower bound $a$ (and no upper bound) you can predict:
$$
z = g(y) = \log\left(y - a\right)
$$
and then apply the inverse
$$
y = e^z + a
$$

If it only has an upper bound $b$ (and no lower bound) then $-y$ has a lower bound ($-b$) and you can predict:
$$
z = g(y) = \log\left(b - y\right)
$$
and then apply the inverse
$$
y = b - e^z
$$